# Difference of Running Maximum of a Reflected Brownian Motion and the Reflected Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion

For a Brownian Motion $W_t$ and $M_t=\sup_{s<t} W_s$, we know $M_t-W_t$ is a reflected Brownian Motion. For a reflected Brownian motion $X_t=|W_t|$ and the running maximum $M'_t=\sup_{s<t} X_s$, what is the distribution of $M'_t-X_t$? Is it a reflected Brownian Motion?